# How many resources do I need to own in Mass Effect 2 to receive a bonus in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In the War Room of the Normandy SV2, Commander Shepard can check the current state of galactic readiness.

While perusing the list, I noticed that I was reciving 25 readiness points from having a high amount of Platinum in Mass Effect 2. How much of each resource do I need to get this bonus? Are there different "tiers" of effectiveness, and is it split across all 4 resources, or is it simply a minimum threshold?

Comment: I received it for having a combined 175k resources. Note that the tooltip *does not* specify that you recieved this bonus for having lots of platinum. It just happens to have the Platinum icon. I suspect this is a coincidence.

Comment: My bonus was 100 points, and I guess I had about 300k total resources. What about yours, @LessPop_MoreFizz?

Comment: @kotekzot mine was 25, so it looks like it does matter.

Comment: Now I don't feel quite as bad about wasting time gathering more resources than necessary.

Comment: I had over 650k+ total resources yet my score was only 10. I think that there may in fact be a correlation between Platinum and the score because Platinum was my lowest upon import (81k).

Comment: I'll have to check when I get home, but I believe that I got a score of 25 there, and I know I finished with very little platinum.  I had upgrades that I couldn't perform in ME2 because I didn't have enough platinum.  However, I did end ME2 with quite a bit of eezo, so I wonder if that factored into it.

Comment: Could this be related to the upgrades you researched instead of the quantity of ores you had on hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the feedback on my website, it appears it does have to do with the Platinum afterall.

If you have 250,000+ total resources with at least 15% being platinum, you get the full 100 point bonus. You can also get 10, 25 points if you have less than the amount required for the maximum bonus of 100. I cannot clarify this but a few people have mentioned it elsewhere.

Source: http://www.gamersheroes.com/mass-effect-3-war-asset-guide

Answer (score 1):

If you get all the research data, have 250k+ resources (at least 15% platinum, 30% element zero), and your entire crew survives the Collector base, you will get 100 points.

Keep your planet depletion/discovery ratio high (discovered planets divided by depleted planets). The Sol section doesn't count, and DLC planets won't count unless it was installed before you started the game.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have over 100K, but less than 999,999 of each mineral, *AND* you have to have entered the orbit, not scanned, of every planet in all systems. At any rate, I have done that on 150+ combined runs through ME2 and ME3 (two levels (Hardcore and Insanity) twice each to max out Level and Weapon tiers for ME2, and two levels of ME3 once each, each time I play). and I have got the 100K Mineral War Asset bonus every single time.  Collector Base survival does not enter into it, only actions related to the planets (amount of minerals collected, and entering the orbit of each planet).