# Do more surplus resources mean greater War Asset?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-2

When I imported by Mass Effect 2 save to Mass Effect 3, one of my War Assets were surplus resources which were collected from the Normandy SR2 when the Alliance was doing the retrofit.

I am wondering, since my score of this asset was 25, would it be higher if I got more surplus resources in Mass Effect 2 and started a new game in Mass Effect 3 with an updated Mass Effect 2 game, would I get a better score or does it remain at 25.

Comment: Can't access the wiki from work, but pretty sure it's a binary -- "if more than X resources from ME2, then +25 war assets".

Comment: Yep, think @Shadur is right. Most of those bonuses are binary, but they might add up to one single display value.

Answer (score 2):

You can get 10, 25, or 100. For 100 some theories are: [250,000+ total resources with at least 15% being platinum](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53570) or [at least of 100,000 of each resource BEFORE you start the Collector Base mission](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/995452-mass-effect-3/65503803). Also, if you have too much, there's a bug where you get only 10.